# Mysql Connect in google cloud sql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

I cannot connect to MySQL from Google cloud compute engine to MySQL storage. When I go to 172.146.221.156/test.php on browser showing an error message like this

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 21
>   Connect Error (2002'

My config file is:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("176.154.226.114", "root", "password");
if (!$conn) 
{
    die('Connect Error (' .mysqli_connect_errno());
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect DATABASE Error TYPE: 2002: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178774/connect-database-error-type-2002-permission-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup security in your Cloud SQL instance? The ip of the compute engine instance should be whitelisted in your cloud sql instance. You can find it under Access control --> Authorized networks

Comment: Yes. My public is in white listed. Now i am facing another issue. I can connect with mysql_connect(). But i cannot connect with mysqli_connect(). What will be the reason?? Does anyone know how?

Answer (score -1):

I'm running on CentOS 7 and ran into the same problem until I found the following post: [Connect DATABASE Error TYPE: 2002: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178774/connect-database-error-type-2002-permission-denied)

Basically `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

That solved my problem without disabling SELinux.

Hope it helps.

Comment: New at this. Not sure how to do 'mark as duplicate'. Just thought what I found could help.

Comment: No worries.  I will do it,

Answer (score -1):

in your google cloud  => go to sql=> click on your instance => connections => Public IP add 0.0.0.0/0 as an allowed network then save.

or write in google my ip and add it if you want only you have a remotely access.