# PHP MySQL PDO Connection to Google Cloud SQL Instance from VM Instance not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

DSN is:
`mysql:dbname='MyDB';unix_socket='/cloudsql/ethereal-accord-123456789:us-central1:dev-Instance'`

Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

PDO Connection Code:

```
 try {
              $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
              // set the PDO error mode to exception

              $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

              echo "Connected successfully";
              return $conn;

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
              echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage().' <BR>';

            }
```

I Cannot seem to find detail information on how to setup the connections correctly.
I follow all documents and activated the permissions for the VM IP, the Client SQL API, and Admin API, and nothing..

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Never seen the `dbname` quoted like that before. Same for `unix_socket`

Answer (score 1):

You don't run the cloudsql proxy or you have defined another location for the socket file. You should check this.

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:3306 &
$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=DATABASE_NAME';
```

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#pdo-tcp

Comment: So that still does not work.. I guess i need to invoke the "cloud_sql_proxy"
but that implies i need to install it in the "Cloud Compute VM", because whne I run
```./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=tcp:3306 &
 
 -bash: ../cloud_sql_proxy: No such file or directory```

again I am running this from a PHP page. - Obviously using my instance name.

I can run the command ``` mysql --host=35.221.000.00x --user=root --password``` and i can connect from VM Compute Cloud to Cloud SQL not a problem.

Comment: ``` $host_name  = "35.222.111.111";  
    $database   = "myDB123";
    $user_name  = "dbuser123";
    $password   = "pass12345";
$GCSocket  ="/cloudsql/ethereal-accord-2000000:us-central1:dev-instance-1";
$GCPort='3306';
    $connect =  mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name,$password,$database,$GCPort,$GCSocket );```

I tried using MYSQLI and I get "Failed to connect to MySQL: Permission denied"
I have the "google-cloud-sdk" installed in the Cloud-Compute-VM, not sure why i need to install the Cloud SQL Proxy if the SQL and Compute are in the same Google Project

Comment: I don't know Google Cloud  very well. But is there a simple DNS-Name like all other cloud services do?

Answer (score 0):

I reverted my code back to MYSqli instead of PDO using these lines

```
$host_name = "35.222.111.111";
$database = "myDB123";
$user_name = "dbuser123";
$password = "pass12345";
$GCSocket ="/cloudsql/ethereal-accord-2000000:us-central1:dev-instance-1"; $GCPort='3306';

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name,$password,$database,$GCPort,$GCSocket )
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() ."<br>";
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL ."<br>";
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL  ."<br><br>";

         } else {

        echo 'DB is connected..! <BR>';
    }

    return $connect;
```

The issue was not with the above code, it worked all along, the issue was with permission.

1. I whitelisted my IP from my Compute Engine VM in the Cloud SQL Server
2. give permission to your Compute Engine Service Account to access the Cloud SQL

   - Cloud SQL Client or Cloud SQL Admin
3. Execute this in the Compute Engine VM:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

and voila... 
 [here is where i found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522467/13632107)!